# Best way to get meaning of a word online programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, winjs

I am developing an app for windows phone (using Javascript ) which requires displaying meaning of a word typed by the user, so what are the ways through which I can get the meaning of the words online, Just the meaning is enough (i mean no need for etymology, etc..).

A file can be used, but it takes too much memory space so what are the alternate approaches ?

Comment: It sounds like you just want some sort of dictionary API? You could check out something like http://www.dictionaryapi.com/

Comment: @KennyBania: yes, a free one without need for api keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the big [list of Dictionary APIs compiled by Programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?keyword=dictionary). [Wordnik's API](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html#!/word/getDefinitions_get_2) looks useful.